# Why does the Java compiler complain about explicit import name conflicts but not import package.*?

Tags: java

The following code compiles and runs correctly.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



class Scanner {
    public Scanner(InputStream in) {

    }
}
public class Foo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(in.getClass());

        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(in2.getClass());
    }
}
```

However, if I change `import java.util.*;` to `import java.util.Scanner;`, I will get the following compiler error.

```
Foo.java:1: error: Scanner is already defined in this compilation unit
```

It seems that in both cases, the compiler should be able to disambiguate equally well, so why does it only complain in the second case?

Comment: I think your class name has something to do with it. You are creatng object of java.util.Scanner not just Scanner. so thats why its working when you have import as java.util.*;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Errors for simple program stop compiling process, please help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094484/java-errors-for-simple-program-stop-compiling-process-please-help)

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran, The question you linked as a duplicate has an extremely convoluted example which I did not even want to scroll down to read. While some facet of it may overlap with this question, I don't think it can qualify as a duplicate.

Comment: @Merlin2011 : Both question have same problem and same answer, but content and the way of asking is different. That's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will happen because you already have a local class named Scanner. You will need to call it with its fully qualified name:

```
java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

Additionally, make your `Scanner` a nested static class:

```
public class Foo {

    private static class Scanner {

        public Scanner(InputStream in) {

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(in.getClass());

        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(in2.getClass());
    }
}
```

## Why this happens

An `import` simply tells the compiler where to look for symbols upon compile time. I don't remember the stage off the top of my head (Preprocessing/compilation), but package imports are not explicit declarations of those class members. By saying `import foo.bar.*`, you are saying "Look in this package directory for Symbols upon compiling", whereas `import foo.bar.Scanner` is saying "Point `Scanner` symbols to this".

In short, a specific import is apparent that you have a symbol for "Scanner", whereas a package import does not specify this specific relation to a symbol.

Comment: The error given by the OP doesn't occur on that line.

Comment: No, the error occurs on the import line. You cannot have that import when declaring non-public classes in that form, so you must use a fully qualified name for them.

Comment: The OP is asking why `import java.util.Scanner` causes a compile error when `import java.util.*` doesn't. For the same code. This answer doesn't quite answer that question.

Comment: yes, thats the point. change the name of the class, say Foo, then just use java.util.Scanner; as import, it will work

Comment: @anonymous I see, I'll try to fill out my answer a little more in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

**Why import `java.util.*` doesn't give error??**

It will not throw error because there is no confusion about the class "`java.util.Scanner`" and your class `Scanner`.

When you use import as `java.util.Scanner`, it conflicts with your class name with the `Scanner` in the `util`.

And that is the reason for error.

Answer (score 0):

This collision of a *single-type-import* declaration with a *top-level* type declaration is described at JSL [§7.5.1. Single-Type-Import Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1):

> If a single-type-import declaration imports a type whose simple name
>   is n, and the compilation unit also declares a top level type (§7.6)
>   whose simple name is n, a compile-time error occurs.

An example cited from [§7.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.1)

```
import java.util.Vector;
class Vector { Object[] vec; }
```

causes a compile-time error because of the duplicate declaration of Vector.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your java class name and importing library name is same. In your case Scanner is refer to the class name not for the library. Changing the class name to something else will be the simplest way to solve the error.